# Is there a difference between WEEK() and DATE_FORMAT() functions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function, date

To extract a week from a date in MySQL, there are several options, but I was asking if there is a difference between `WEEK(date, 0)` and `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%U')` from an implementation point of view.

I mean, the 2 functions return the same results, but in the background, is it the same implementation? Does one call the other? Is there a deprecated one?

I've searched the [MySQL date and time functions documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) without finding any answer. Thanks for your enlightenment!

*Note : depending on what you want on the output, you should have to use one or the other with different parameters (0 to 52 weeks or 0 to 53? starts on Sunday or Monday? First week with at least 3 days?), but I'm asking about this particular case.*

Comment: You may have to look into the source code for this... Any specific reason why you want to know?

Comment: Most of the date functions are just convenience shortcuts to the bigger `date_format()` call. YEAR() -> `date_format('Y')` and so on. Easier to remember 'year()' than have to dig up the format codes for 'date_format()' each time

Comment: @Pekka I'm not a MySql expert, so I wanted to learn, and know which one is better to use.

Comment: @Baztoune fair enough... they seem to be doing the same thing and as @Marc says, they are probably just shortcuts. Using WEEK() should be fine.

Comment: @Marc B Thanks. So, that might be a shortcut, with the same implementation?

Comment: Not having looked into the mysql source, can't say 100% for sure yes, but otherwise, having multiple date/time implementations leaves open the possibility of a bug causing `week()` returning different results than `date_format('%U')` (or whatever the exact mapping is). Far simpler to provide one interface to the same backend, than having to support multiple backends.

Comment: @Baz if you have no specific reason to look at this extremely closely, I think it is safe to say you can use either.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT results in a string/text, while WEEK() results in an integer, that's one difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commentors said, week() seems to be a shortcut for the general date_format() function.
Plus as @nos mentioned, date_format() returns a string (due to its general behavior I guess), although week() returns an integer.

I wanted to investigate to verify that theory, and looked into the source code.
The two functions are implemented in the [item_timefunc.cc](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/mysql-trunk/view/head:/sql/item_timefunc.cc) file.

- date_format calls make_date_time, implemented [line 633](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/mysql-trunk/view/head:/sql/item_timefunc.cc#L633)
- week leads to [line 1232](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/mysql-trunk/view/head:/sql/item_timefunc.cc#L1232)

And guess what? They both lead to the [calc_week function](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/mysql-trunk/view/head:/sql/sql_time.cc#L103) in sql_time.cc
So, `week(date)` is not really a shortcut for `date_format(date, '%v')`, but they both call the same function, after computing the parameters from the input.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that they return different data types. WEEK() returns an integer whereas DATE_FORMAT() returns a character value.

That's a **fundamental** difference.